# Windows/Microsoft Update - Online Database and manual file download

Tags: windows-update

I remember a while ago that I could download any Windows/Microsoft update I wanted by going to a site on Microsoft.com, and just clicking download against any update.

It also had a brilliant search feature so that I could type either an update number or a basic search term and it would find all the certified packages that can be delivered through Windows update (WHQL drivers etc.)

It is driving me mad, I have spent the best part of the day (along with other tasks!) trying to find this link!

Does anyone know what it is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you referring to the [Windows Update Catalog](http://windowsupdate.microsoft.com/catalog)? That's the only one that comes to mind and offers the functionality you want.

Comment: Forgot it was Internet Explorer only - Anyway, I just forgot what it was called and could not find it in my favourites - have been looking pretty much all day for this. Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem! It's not that easy to find, to be honest :)

Comment: I was searching for update directory, list, offline and more - never looked for catalogue!, however I am wondering if this was one of the sites I found, but because of the message about browser, I ignored it :S I hope not! but anyway, thanks again! shame I can't give extra reward / bounty on correct answers :(

Comment: It's no problem, I'm glad I could help! I know how frustrating it is to look for something but can't find it. By the way, this is how I remembered about Windows Update Catalog; I found this article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323166